# Telnet: How do I un-escape?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, telnet

I know that when connected via Telnet, I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to escape.  This brings me to the telnet command line interface.  How do I get back to my telnet session?

I occasionally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> by accident and would like to resume my work.  I use telnet on all three major machines (MacOS, Windows, & Linux).

Note that I am not trying to quit telnet; I just want to resume my session.

Comment: It could be a duplicate, but none of the suggested answers seem that simple...

Comment: How could anybody think that this question is a duplicate of that one?  They're complete opposites!  One is "How do I do ***A*** without doing ***B***?", and the other is "How do I do ***B*** without doing ***A***?".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just press return, to leave the prompt and go back to your session.

Comment: Ahhgh!  (hits head against screen)  So simple!  The prompt doesn't redisplay, so it looks like it's hung.  But you are absolutely right.  I knew there had to be some simple solution.  Thanks!

Comment: It's something that I noticed a while back, when there was less documentation.  I can see that it is documented, e.g., [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491013.aspx): To return to the Telnet session, press ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

Try it,
telnet> status
or
telnet> send escape
Then, you can get back to your escaped telnet session.